# how to add to dictionary using textbox

Tags: c#

how do i use two textboxes `textbox1` and `textbox2` to add a new key and value to a `dictionary` and store the value after pressing the button Add

in this case key = `3` value = `take 3`

***Class Code with Dictionary***

```
class MyCipher: ICipherDecipher
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string> alphabet { get; set; }

        public MyCipher()
        {
            alphabet = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            alphabet.Add("4", " take 4");
            alphabet.Add("3", " take 3");
            alphabet.Add("5d", " for 5 days");
        }

        class Code
        {
            public string MyCode;
            public string MyDecoded;


            public Code(string code, string decode)
            {
                MyCode = code;
                MyDecoded = decode;
            }


        }
```

***Main Code***

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private MyCipher myCipher;
        public Form1()
        {
            myCipher = new MyCipher();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
     
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(myCipher.alphabet, null);

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }
```

[image: Application ----Image]

Comment: im new guys , i need your help please

Comment: `myCipher.alphabet.Add(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao you could add an new value in `alphabet` dictionary like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   myCipher.alphabet.Add(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to store values you add to dictionary modify your code like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private MyCipher myCipher;
    public Form1()
    {
        myCipher = new MyCipher();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
 
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // load data saved
        if (File.Exists(@"D:\myfile.txt")) {
           Dictionary<string,string> result = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\myfile.txt").Select(x => x.Split(";")).ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);  
           foreach (string key in result.Keys) {    
               myCipher.alphabet.Add(key, result[key]); 
           }
        }
        listBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(myCipher.alphabet, null);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       myCipher.alphabet.Add(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
       // rebind data to show new values on listBox
       listBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(myCipher.alphabet, null);
       // save dictionary
       File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\myfile.txt", myCipher.alphabet.Select(s => String.Format("{0};{1}", s.Key, s.Value)));
    }
```

Comment: Adding to the dictionary will not update the ListBox

Comment: Yes? And what does it means this line `listBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(myCipher.alphabet, null);`?

Comment: i tried the code but its not adding to the dictionary or its not storing?? i cant access the values i input

Comment: how do i store this value to then use after i close the program??

Comment: Oh wait but this is another problem. You want to store the dictionary somewhere and recall it on next form open... In this case you have 2 choices: or save values in file and on form load you read the file and re-create dictionary, or use `Properties.Settings`. Note: in `Properties.Settings` you cannot store a dictionary, so you have to create a string with values and then on form load, read the properties and re-create dictionary again. If you don't know how to create `Properties.Settings` watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RITSf841Tbo) video.

Comment: how do i do that ?? saving on file, please help

Comment: When you want to save all the dictionary content just add this line: `File.WriteAllLines("myfile.txt", myCipher.alphabet.Select(s => String.Format("{0};{1}", s.Key, s.Value)));`

Comment: on Form load or button click event??

Comment: on button click event

Comment: Then to realod data from file saved, add this lines `Dictionary<string,string> result = File.ReadAllLines(@"path to myfile.txt").Select(x => x.Split(";")).ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);                                                                                                                     foreach (string key in result.Keys)
{
   myCipher.alphabet.Add(key, result[key]);
}`

Comment: do i have to add that code in my class on `alphabet` ???

Comment: This operation must be done on form load before calling `BindingSource`.

Comment: I updated my answer with all the code you need to save and reload dictionary from text file. Take a look.

Comment: D:\New folder (2)' is denied , i am getting this error when i add the path

Comment: I edit again my code. Chek now if it works (I putted a fixed path "D:\myfile.txt")

Comment: When i reopened i got error  "An item with the same key has already been added" at ` myCipher.alphabet.Add(key, result[key]);` , should i remove the list of things in my dictionary class `alphabet`???

Comment: It was a pleasure. Have a nice day :)

Comment: same applies to you

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the Add button1_Click will be triggered so we need to implement the logic in that method

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // You need to get the values of the key and value
    
    string key = textbox1.Text;
    string value = textbox2.Text;
    myCipher.alphabet.Add(key, value);
    listBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(myCipher.alphabet, null);
}
```

Please try this and add a comment if something does not work.

Comment: What `InputKey` and `InputValue` are? Please explain.

Comment: I have added the comments, I was not sure what is the name for Input's Key and Value

Comment: He writes textbox1 and textbox2. What do you need more????

Comment: I didn't look at that while I was writing the answer

Comment: how can i then store this value in the dictionary??

Comment: I'm adding the values to the dictionary. You are not able to see them in the Dictionary?

Comment: when i reopen the application the values will be gone